# EJS conditional statement change CSS

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

I have loop in EJS and I want to set css based on my data:

```
<% dummies.forEach(function(dummy) { %>
   <div class="panel panel-???">
   </div>
<% }) %>
```

my data:

```
var dummies = [{ 
    type: "funny",
    sure: "Yes" // this should generate panel-success
}, { 
    type: "funny", // this should generate panel-a
    sure: "No"
}, { 
    type: "happy", // this should generate panel-b
    sure: "No",
}];
```

So whenever `sure` attribute is `Yes`, it generates `panel-success`. Otherwise, it generates css based on `type` attribute.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create object like this:

```
<%
let cssClass = {
    funny: {
        Yes: "success",
        No: "a"
    },
    happy: {
        No: "b"
    }
} 
%>
```

Then you should just output value in template:

```
<% dummies.forEach(function(dummy) { %>
   <div class="panel panel-<%= cssClass[dummy.type][dummy.sure] %>">
   </div>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: it works, thank you! But, this way, I have to list all possibilities of those 2 attributes though (type and sure). Actually whenever "sure" is "Yes", it's always panel-success no matter what value for "type", so I'm wondering if it's possible to make it shorter...

Comment: So if sure==="yes" panel-type="success"

Answer (score 2):

I think this code will help :
`<a class="<%= 1==2 ? 'active' : '' %>" href="#"></a>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code...

```
  <% dummies.forEach(function(dummy) { %>
    <div class="panel panel-
      <% if (dummy.sure==="yes") { %> 
        success
      <% else %>
        <%= dummy.type %>
      >
    </div>
  <% }) %>
```

You can just wrap your logic inside the EJS operators.  It looks a little messy but it is what it is.  Depending on how your server side is set up, you could also pass in parameters from the server side, instead of doing the logic on the client side.

The best way would depend on where the heavy lifting is done as far as trips to the database and any other logic going on.